# How to preserve scope in componentized Angular app containing a dialog that serves a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a question about how to pass scope to a template rendered from a directive. This seems like it should be so straight forward but somehow I am having a lot of trouble getting it to work.

My HTML (simplified for brevity) is as follows:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <md-content>
    <!-- strangely TestController as tc doesnt work -->
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
      <div ng-click="showDialog();">Show</div> <!-- this also doesnt seem to work.. -->
    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

And then the application (contained in a script tag on index.html):

```
// app -- using components
var app = angular.module('ctrlApp', 
  ['components', 'ngMaterial']);

// removed app.config from ngMaterial for brevity
```

The app contains a controller that has a function to show a mdDialog:

```
//controller
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $log, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.items = [{'title': 1},{'title': 2}];
    // open modal
    $scope.showDialog = function() {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: 'dialog.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            clickOutsideToClose:true,
            controller: function() {
                // scope from parent persists here as expected
                console.dir($scope.items);

                // used to wire up dialog specific UI behavior
                $scope.cancel = function() { $mdDialog.hide(); }
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Dialog.html just renders out the directive in a modal:

```
<md-dialog aria-label="test">
  <form ng-cloak>
  <!-- rendering a directive here -->
    <my-directive></my-directive>
  </form>
</md-dialog>
```

And finally, returning back to the app, here is the directive:

```
// link up a directive that is rendered in the model form
var d = angular.module('components', []);
d.directive('myDirective', function() {

  function link(scope, element, attributes ) { 
    console.log("scope.items are ", scope.items); }

    return({
      restrict: "E",
      controller: 'TestController',
      link: link,
      templateUrl: 'directive.html',
    });
});
```

And finally the directive.html template:

```
<div>
  <h1>my Directive template</h1>
  <pre> Empty!: {scope.items}</pre>
</div>
```

I am confused as to how I can get the scope that is created by the TestController into the template that is rendered by the directive. It works fine all the way up to the 'link' function but not in the directive's template...

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks
- X

Answer (score 0):

You have done mistake in directive.html,

Your code:

```
<div>
  <h1>my Directive template</h1>
  <pre> Empty!: {scope.items}</pre>
</div>
```

Expected code:

```
    <div>
      <h1>my Directive template</h1>
      <pre> Empty!: {{scope.items[0]}}</pre> //Here you need to pass Array index
    </div>
```

Here i given you running code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-app="ctrlApp">
            <md-content>
                <!-- strangely TestController as tc doesnt work -->
                <div ng-controller="TestController">
                    <div ng-click="showDialog();">Show</div>
                    <!-- this also doesnt seem to work.. -->
                </div>
            </md-content>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /** Own Module **/
            var d = angular.module('components', []);
            d.directive('myDirective', function() {

                function link(scope, element, attributes) {
                    console.log("scope.items are ", scope.items);
                }

                return ({
                    restrict: "E",
                    controller: 'TestController',
                    link: link,
                    template: '<div>\
      <h1>my Directive template</h1>\
      <pre> Empty!: {{items[0]}}</pre>\
    </div>',
                });
            });
            var app = angular.module('ctrlApp', ['components', 'ngMaterial']);

            app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $log, $mdDialog) {
                $scope.items = [{
                    'title': 1
                }, {
                    'title': 2
                }];
                // open modal
                $scope.showDialog = function() {
                    $mdDialog.show({
                        template: '<md-dialog aria-label="test">\
      <form ng-cloak>\
        <my-directive></my-directive>  </form>\
    </md-dialog>',
                        parent: angular.element(document.body),
                        clickOutsideToClose: true,
                        controller: function() {
                            // scope from parent persists here as expected
                            console.dir($scope.items);

                            // used to wire up dialog specific UI behavior
                            $scope.cancel = function() {
                                $mdDialog.hide();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                };
            });
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Hamid: Thanks for the code, that does work, but the second I change the directives link function to pull in an external template, it doesn't work, i.e.: `template: 'directive.html'`, even if in the `directive.html` file I use `{scope.items[0]}` so it seems that angular is not able to retain scope when you pull in external html files this way?

Comment: If it is work in template property, so must work in templateUrl property , as you given **directive.html** expression {{scope variable}}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the scope to template try something like this

In **Dialog.html**

In ***Directive*** just add the following line

return({
      restrict: "E",
      controller: 'TestController',
      scope:{
         item:'='
      },
      link: link,
      templateUrl: 'directive.html',
    });

Hope this helps.

If you want to pass scope to $mdDialog look at the link below.
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1531

Comment: Hi Vikram, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that does not work either. It throws an error: `Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'items' used with directive 'someDirective' is non-assignable!` ... I guess I will go back to just inlining all the HTML... so much for angular making web development easier ! hahah